# Cordova hideKeyboardAccessoryBar not working

Tags: android, ios, cordova, ionic-framework

I access the plugin in `$ionicPlatform.ready` like this (default in ionic)

```
if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
}
```

If i understood it right the `hideKeyboardAccessoryBar` should hide the Keyboard if i press the go, submit, next, ... Button.
[image]

But if i click one of those Buttons, the keyboard doesn't hide. Neither in the iosEmulator nor on a real device.

Comment: check my answer and let me know if it helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `cordova.plugins.Keyboard.close();` to hide keyboard. `hideKeyboardAccessoryBar` is used to hide/disable accessory bar of keyboard, not whole keyboard.

Comment: But how can i check if the user clicked on the go,submit,... Button? Without that information i don't know when to hide it.

Comment: Of course this go or submit button is triggering some function, usualy when you use form, then function in `ng-submit` is called in these events.In that function you can close that.

Comment: Please have a look at this too http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/getting-the-keyboard-go-button-to-act-like-the-app-submit-was-clicked/5305

Comment: It is possible to check the KeyCode. Checking for 13 and calling cordova.plugins.Keyboard.close(); did the trick.

Comment: I am glad :) I did same for my project ;)